# RecyclerView With Fragment is not Working! Showing Error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

`RecyclerView`  with `Fragment` is not working, its showing error and application get crash at runtime .

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {
  String [] names={"Nitin","Manish","Ankit","Hardik","Mayur","Mayank"};

  RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
  Context context;
  RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list,container,false);

    setupRecyclerView();
    return v;
  }

  private void setupRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_nit);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayout= new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    mLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    mAdapter= new RecyclerAdapter(context,names);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  }
```

Its showing error at run time and app get crash before starting,

and here is adapter class for that `RecyclerView`:

```
Context context;
String[] names;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, String[] names) {
  this.context = context;
  this.names = names;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

  RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
  View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw_list,parent,false);

  vh=new ViewHolder(v);

  return (ViewHolder) vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  holder.txt.setText(names[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
  return 0;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  TextView txt;
  public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    txt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_listtext);

  }
}
```

its showing:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.hp.newfragment, PID: 3354
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.hp.newfragment/com.example.hp.newfragment.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error
>   inflating class fragment

Thanks for help in advance ......

Comment: post your xml code too

Comment: Show your layout file.

Comment: fragment_list.xml<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_nit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: fragment_display.xml<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>

Comment: raw_list.xml <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_listtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_nit);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayout= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        mAdapter= new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),names);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U have to set Layout manager

like This

```
private void setupRecyclerView() {
mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_nit);
LinearLayoutManager mLayout= new LinearLayoutManager(context);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayout);// here u have to add 
mLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```